# How can I interpolate a set of precomputed functions in OpenCL?

Tags: c++, opencl, interpolation

I'm working with an OpenCL kernel where I need to use associated Legendre polynomials.

These are a set of fairly difficult to compute polynomials indexed by a integer n and m orders, and accepting a real argument. The specifics of the actual polynomials is irrelevant, since I have a (slow) host-side function that can generate them, but the kernel side function would need to look something like:

```
float legendre(int n, int m, float z)
 {
    float3 lookupCoords;
    lookupCoords.x = n;
    lookupCoords.y = m;
    lookupCoords.z = z;

    //Do something here to interpolate Z for a given N and M...
 }
```

I want to interpolate along the Z axis, but just have nearest neighbor for the n and m axes since they're only defined for integer values. A benefit of Z is that it's only defined between -1 and 1, so it already looks a lot like a texture coordinate.

**How can I accomplish this with a sampler and lookup tables in OpenCL?**

My first thought was to attempt to use a 3D texture filled with precomputed orders, but I only want to interpolate along one dimension (the real or Z argument), and I'm not sure what this would look like in OpenCL C.

Comment: Linear interpolation or exponential? Many point method or some higher order versions?

Comment: Linear should be fine. I was hoping to use whatever hardware accelerated interpolation OpenCL provides.

Comment: Why not 2D texture? x as x, y as y , z as color? so just using read_imagef(image, sampler, coord); cannot give any interpolation?(even at the edges)

Comment: Z is another input, so it's a function of n, m, and z.

Answer (score 3):

In OpenCL 1.1 use `read_imagef` with an `image3d_t` for the first parameter, a `sampler_t` created with `CLK_FILTER_LINEAR` for the second paramter, and finally a `float4 coord` for the third parameter with your coordinates to read from.

To interpolate only along *one* axis, let that coordinate's value be any float value but make the other two coordinates `floor(value) + 0.5f`. This will make them not interpolate. Like this (only interpolating z):

```
float4 coordinate = (float4)(floor(x) + 0.5f, floor(y) + 0.5f, z, 0.0f);
```

In OpenCL 1.2 you could use image arrays but I'm not sure it would be any faster and NVIDIA does not support OpenCL 1.2 on Windows.

Comment: Update: NVIDIA supports OpenCL 1.2 on Windows now.